# Firebase cloud messaging authorizion error

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to send FCM push notification to my android app 
on from postman i have on my developer console two api keys when i try to use the first one i get this response from FCM :

```
Unauthorized

Error 401
```

and when i try the second one i get this response from FCM :

```
Error=MissingRegistration
```

[image: request image]

and i have this data in the body :

```
{ "data":{
"score":"5x1",
"time":"15:10"
}
,
"to":"*******"
}
```

the token is working fine  and i have  test it in the firebase console 
what the problem could be and what is the solution

Comment: MissingRegistration usually indicates that your to field is empty, if it is not empty, I'd expect you to be getting InvalidRegistration. Also are you using GCM or FCM on the client side to generate the InstanceID token you are using in the to field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error 401 Unauthorized` comes beacuse of wrong server key.

**To solve this error:**
Go to your project settings in `firebase console`.
Click on `Cloud Messaging` and copy `Server Key` mentioned in that page.

Let me know, if more help is required.

Comment: i have done that and i had the second case of my question

Comment: i get this response Error=MissingRegistration

Comment: Have you added TokenID to the post request?

Comment: i have this data in the body { "data":{
"score":"5x1",
"time":"15:10"
}
,
"to":"token"
}

Comment: Please try change your `to` key to `registration_ids`.

Comment: Check that the request contains a registration token (in the registration_id in a plain text message, or in the to or registration_ids field in JSON).

Comment: If you just want to test push notification, then you can also check it on `firebase console`.

Comment: Same things i have done but i still getting missing registration